# Password input field doesn't work in ios safari

Tags: html, ios, iphone, safari

If you take a look at this page on an iPhone with safari, you see that when you tap the password input field and then start to type, what you typed in doesn't show on the screen and the cursor stays the same.

I'm very curious what this could be. I believe there isn't a HTML error or syntax problem.. but maybe I'm wrong. The HTML is generated by PHP, if that's of any help.

Please let me know if this is fixable and where I need to look. Thanks!

UPDATE:

Fixed. Link is not working anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using z-index on top of an image that overlays the input field. I think that in this case it's better to make either the div that's holding the `z-index` either smaller or get rid of it all together.

Comment: I disabled the z-index and now it works, thanks! I got rid of it all together now.

Comment: @Andre if an answer solved your question, don't forget to choose an answer as best answer :p

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that your HTML is correct?

Correct syntax for a password field:

```
<input type="password" name="password">
```

The syntax on your page:

```
<input class="password" type="text" name="password" placeholder="**********" />
```

There may be some customisations in the class for "password". Anyway, it's not the standard way of defining password field, so not all browsers will behave as you expected.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention that I changed it from password type to text type to see if the problem persisted, which it does.. So it's a problem with the input fields in general I presume

Comment: Well, you should change it back for SO folks to test and find out what's wrong. Once you alter the way it works, nobody will be able to see what is wrong with your page. By the way, your current page seems "normal" in both Safari on my Mac and iPhone.

Comment: Seriously, I don't see the symptom that you had posted after testing several times on my iPhone 4S Safari, Chrome and Firefox (on PC). If you are using an older-version Safari or browser, may be upgrade it and test again.

Comment: See the answer of @bdv beneath, I disabled the z-index but yesterday but forgot to comment, so that's why it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just add autocomplete="current-password" attribute to input element.

```
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password"/>
```